# count total users for each date laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i need help please i have mysql table :

```
id   username   password     created_at
1    admin       *****       2020-07-06
2    user        *****       2020-07-06
3    user2       *****       2020-07-07
```

my controller :

```
$count = User::where('created_at', '>=', '2020-06-29')
            ->get(['id', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') as date")])
            ->pluck('id', 'date');
```

now the problem is when i see result, it give me for example

```
2020-07-06 : 2
2020-07-07 : 3
```

but i want to have count ...

Please someone help me thanks ??

Comment: @Mantelijo solution will work. The error in your solution is that you aren't grouping and in the first attempt, using >=.

Comment: Glad he helped you solve it, even if you needed to add pluck!

Comment: On second glance if you want date => count, his solution doesn't fully work. You will need selectRaw('created_at', 'count(*) as created' )->pluck('created', 'created_at');

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to construct a query that uses `GROUP BY` similar to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), created_at FROM users GROUP BY created_at
```

In laravel you could use eloquent to do this:

```
User::select('created_at')->selectRaw('count(*)')->groupBy('created_at')->get()
```

Comment: thanks for help. but how to add get data and pluck in your query ? I want to have the same question, I just need to have count ?